# 'LGSideMenucontroller' not open in all viewcontroller in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I am using 'LGSideMenuController' for sidemenu. Now in my app 'loginviewcontroller' then 'otpviewcontroller' and then 'homeviewcontroller' and other 'viewcontroller'. now my side menu open in all viewcontroller after 'homeviewcontroller'. I am able to open side menu from 'homeviewcontroller'. but in other viewcontroller I am not.

I did code for open sidemenu in 'appdelegate.swift' and also in 'homeviewcontroller'.

in my appdelegate.swift my code for open sidemenu.

```
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let rootviewcontroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
    let navigation = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: rootviewcontroller)
    let sideMenuVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuVC") as! SideMenuVC

    let sideMenuController = LGSideMenuController(rootViewController: navigation,
                                                  leftViewController: sideMenuVC,
                                                  rightViewController: nil)
    sideMenuController.leftViewWidth = 280.0
    sideMenuController.leftViewPresentationStyle = .scaleFromBig

    self.window?.rootViewController = sideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and in my homeviewcontroller i make code like this

```
@IBAction func sideMenuAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.sideMenuController?.showLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

it works in homeviewcontroller but other viewcontroller not working.

Comment: By other view controllers you mean when you push another controller? If you can add a small video of your problem that would really help

Comment: yes. when i goto another viewcontroller . my side menu not open in that viewcontroller and also previous viewcontroller. it open only one time.

Comment: I tried replicating your scenario and I was able to open the side menu controller multiple times in the root and other pushed controllers as well no problem. Can you please post a video of your simulator or device showing your problem?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cGi5tdtZIbWmk_B-N3assbELhCwvqVPp you can download demo here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Container View and make it the root controller. Then, you'd be able to achieve what you're trying to do

Comment: sorry. don't understand.